# Vue.js axios delete request is deleting but table won't reset

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I am having trouble with axios delete request. I get the following errors when I click the delete button

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isExpanded')"
```

and

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isExpanded')
```

The data gets deleted but only after I refresh the browser.
Please let me know what I am missing in my deleteNetworkGroup method? I included the axios get request

```js
async getNetworks(audId) 
  {
      try
      {
          const response = await this.axios.get("/s/audiences/network-groups?audId=" + audId);

          if (!this.networkGroups[audId])
          {
              this.$set(this.networkGroups, audId, {});
              this.$set(this.networkGroups[audId], 'isExpanded', false);
          }

          this.$set(this.networkGroups[audId], 'data', response.data ? response.data.data : []);
      }
      catch (error)
      {
          if (error.message && error.message.includes("404"))
          {
              if (!this.networkGroups[audId])
              {
                  this.$set(this.networkGroups, audId, {});
                  this.$set(this.networkGroups[audId], 'isExpanded', false);
              }

              this.$set(this.networkGroups[audId], 'data', []);
          }
          else
          {
              console.log(error.message);
          }
      }

  },


deleteNetworkGroup(id, index) 
  {

      axios.delete(projConfig.apiRoot + '/s/audiences/network-groups/' + id)
          .then(response => 
          {
              this.networkGroups.splice(index, 1)
                  .push(response.data.data);
          })
          .catch((error) => 
          {
              console.log(error);
          });
  },
```

```html
<button type="button" class="delete_btn">
  <div class="trash_icon" @click="deleteNetworkGroup(networkGroup.id, index)">
   <font-awesome-icon icon="trash" />
  </div>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the second parameter (Index) when calling the `@click` handler `deleteNetworkGroup`. Could solve your issue.

Comment: I have the index param in my code. I am getting the same error. I updated the snippet.

Comment: Where does your index param come from? Is it inside a v-for loop? Please do a console log inside your method to see if the params are set correctly.

Comment: You could also try to use Array.filter instead